# Filter array of json flutter dio

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dio

I have to filter the json shown below and create an object of type operation, the thing that interests me is to create either a json(below) object for each element of this array by iterating only the **scheduled_operation_id** field, to do it I use this code, when i iterate the array with the below code i have the following error, how do i fix it?

**Error:**

```
     Errore: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>'
 is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' in type cast
```

**Flutter Code:**

```
class Operation {
  late int id, usage_based_maintenance_id, order, user;
  late bool completed;
  late String title, description;

  Operation(this.id, this.usage_based_maintenance_id, this.order, this.user,
      this.completed, this.title, this.description);

  Operation.small(this.id, this.title,this.description);
}

     static Future<List<Operation>> getList(Maintenance man) async {
        List<Operation> listOperation = [];
        try {
          var path = '/maintenance/scheduled/operation/complete/' + man.id.toString();
          Map value = await apiRequest(path, {}, UrlRequest.GET, true);
          print("titolo: "+value['response']['scheduled_operation_id']['title']);
          listOperation = (value['response']['scheduled_operation_id'] as Iterable).map((e) => Operation.small(e["id"],e["title"],e["description"])).toList();
        } catch (err) {
          print("Errore: " + err.toString());
        }
        print("lista operazioni caricate" + listOperation.length.toString());
        return listOperation;
      }
```

**JSON:**

```
{
    "version": "v1",
    "timezone": "Europe/Rome",
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2022-10-17T12:07:42.770471Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-10-27T10:21:39.732008Z",
        "completed": true,
        "comment": "null",
        "user": {
            "username": "administrator_test",
            "email": "administrator_test@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "administrator",
            "last_name": "test"
        },
        "programmed_date": "2022-10-09",
        "programmed_hour": "11:00:00",
        "scheduled_maintenance_title": "asdasd",
        "scheduled_operation_title": "Nuova",
        "scheduled_operation_id": {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-10-17T12:07:23.473907Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-10-17T12:07:23.473945Z",
            "title": "asdasd",
            "scheduled_maintenance_id": {
                "id": 1,
                "created_at": "2022-10-17T12:07:23.406877Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-10-17T12:07:23.406905Z",
                "title": "Nuova",
                "description": "asdasd",
                "trigger_hour": "10:00:00",
                "trigger_day": [
                    0,
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    4,
                    5,
                    6
                ],
                "start_date": "2022-10-09",
                "end_date": "2022-10-17",
                "enabled": true,
                "results": []
            },
            "description": "asdasd",
            "order": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "scheduled_operation_id" key is not a list, so you will get an error if you try to iterate in it

Comment: scheduled_operation_id is in list check json @batuhand